# Correct usage of strip tool

Tags: linker, ld, toolchain, binutils, linaro

Unpacked [Linaro GCC 6.2-2016.11](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/) toolchain occupies almost 3.4 GB of disc space and I want to make it smaller. My target is *armv7-a+vfpv3+hard_float* so I have already removed things I do not need (like `ld.gold`, libraries for `Thumb`, `v8-a`, `v7ve` etc) but it still occupies almost 1 GB.

So I want to use [`strip`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html) tool to remove redundant information from its binaries.

My main question is **how to use *strip* safety, correctly and efficiently in this case?**

In general we have different binary files in toolchain to which we can apply `strip`: `*.exe`, `*.a`, `*.o`.

As I can judge I can apply `strip -s` (remove all symbols) only to `*.exe` files (i.g. *arm-eabi-gcc.exe*). **Am I right?**

**Is it possible to apply `strip` to libraries (i.g. *libgcc.a*)?**
As I understood (see example above) symbols in libraries may be needed for further processing.

**If yes, should I use `--strip-debug` instead (remove debugging symbols only)?**

Example below illustrates these questions and reveals more.

Assume that we have three files:

```
// main.c:
#include "libgcc_test.h"
int main(void)
{
    do_something();
    return 0;
}

// libgcc_test.c:
void do_something(void)
{
    return;
}

// libgcc_test.h:
void do_something(void);
```

In general we just compile each file separately to get object files which can be linked together:

```
$ ./arm-eabi-gcc.exe main.c -c
$ ./arm-eabi-gcc.exe libgcc_test.c -c
```

By analyzing object files we can see that *do_something* symbol is defined in *libgcc_test.o* and undefined in *main.o*, as expected:

```
$ ./arm-eabi-nm.exe main.o
         U do_something
00000000 T main

$ ./arm-eabi-nm.exe libgcc_test.o
00000000 T do_something
```

If we apply `strip -s` to both files or only to *main.o* and try to link them, it works:

```
$ ./arm-eabi-nm.exe main.o
arm-eabi-nm.exe: main.o: no symbols
$ ./arm-eabi-nm.exe libgcc_test.o
arm-eabi-nm.exe: libgcc_test.o: no symbols
$ ./arm-eabi-ld.exe libgcc_test.o main.o -o main
arm-eabi-ld.exe: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00008000
```

But if we apply `strip -s` only to *libgcc_test.o*, linker produces error message:

```
$ ./arm-eabi-strip.exe -s libgcc_test.o
$ ./arm-eabi-ld.exe libgcc_test.o main.o -o main
arm-eabi-ld.exe: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00008000
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `do_something'
```

As I understand presence of unresolved symbol in an object file forces linker to resolve it. **What happens if I remove this symbol from an object file before linking?**

**Is it correct and safe to remove symbols from object files before linking them together? If yes, which symbols can be removed?**

In real project if we apply `strip -s` to toolchain libraries (*libgcc.a*, *libc.a*, *libm.a*, *librdimon.a* etc) it similarly produces a lot of `"undefined reference to..."` messages during linking stage.

But if we use `--strip-debug` option, linker produces messages for libraries like `skipping incompatible libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc`. If we revert libraries, it is linked successfuly.

**What does `skipping incompatible...` message mean in this case?**

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize how I did it. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

I just removed unnecessary libraries/executables and applied `strip -s` to `*.exe` files only.

After that all the toolchain appeared to be *~230 MB*.